# ProxyError: None: Max retries exceeded with url:http://localhost:4000/generate-orders/get-orders

Tags: python, python-requests, celery

I am using celery to run some task. 
below is my celery task written in python:

```
@celery.task
def getOrders():
   r = requests.get('http://localhost:4000/generate-orders/get-orders')
   print r
```

Below is my node js code which call above defined celery task:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var celery = require('../celery'),
    client = celery.createClient({
        CELERY_BROKER_URL: 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'
    });

client.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

/*client.on('connect', function() {
    client.call('tasks.every_30_seconds');
});*/
client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('hi');
    var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/3 * * * *', function(){
        console.log('Today is recognized by Rebecca Black!');
        client.call('tasks.getOrders');
    });
});
```

As written in above code I am using node-schedule package to call celery task periodically after every 3 mins.

But requests.get gives error:

> ProxyError: None: Max retries exceeded with
>   url:http://localhost:4000/generate-orders/get-orders

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you try out your HTTP GET manually?

Comment: Yes when I hit this url from browser it works.

Comment: ... and if you try it from the command line on the machine celery is running on?

Comment: Celery is running on my local machine and I don't know how can try hitting this manually from command. Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

Please write a python script to run on the command line of the machine.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost:4000/generate-orders/get-orders')
print(r.text)
```

If this fails too there is a problem with this http endpoint.

Comment: I have tried same code on different machine and it worked. Few minutes back I have run set http_proxy=http://your_proxy:your_port(with my proxy IP and 8080 port) command on my system, can it be a reason I am getting proxy error?

Comment: Can be. This error means that the http endpoint answers in an unexpected way. Could be a proxy like in your case or a firewall or something like that.